# C++ matrix multiplication returning pointers for first and last 2 rows of array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, matrix, operator-overloading

I have an extremely infuriating problem with my C++ assignment.

We are tasked to perform matrix multiplication within C++ using dynamic memory allocation. For the most part, the program works fine, BUT, the assignment operator, as well as (maybe) matrix multiplication seems to not work.

Basically, my program when run performs the matrix multiplication without a problem, however the returned Matrix object does not seem to be performing that greatly!

Here is the relevant code for the Matrix.h file

```
    class Matrix
{

    //Pointer matrix
    int **matrix;

    //height and width of the matrix
    int height;
    int width;

    //declaring all public functions to be included in the Matrix object
public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(int, int);
    ~Matrix();
    void constructor(int, int);
    void destruct();
    int getHeight() const;
    int getWidth() const;
    int getElement(int, int) const;
    void setElement(int, int, int);
    int* getColumn(int) const;
    void setColumn(int, int*);
    int* getRow(int) const;
    void setRow(int, int*);
    void fillMatrix(int);
    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix &m);
    const Matrix operator+(const Matrix &m);
    const Matrix operator-(const Matrix &m);
    const Matrix operator*(const Matrix &m);
    bool operator==(const Matrix &m);
    bool operator!=(const Matrix &m);
};

Matrix::Matrix()
{
    matrix = new int*[1];
}

Matrix::Matrix(int x, int y)
{
    constructor(x,y);
}

Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    destruct();
}

/**
This function contructs the matrix using given heights and widths
(for colums and rows) and then allocates the memory for this
object
*/
void Matrix::constructor (int matrixHeight, int matrixWidth)
{
    height = matrixHeight;
    width = matrixWidth;
    matrix = new int *[matrixHeight];
    for ( int i = 0; i < matrixHeight; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new int[matrixWidth];
    }

    //initialising all areas in array
    for ( int i = 0; i < matrixHeight; i++)
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < matrixWidth; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
}

/**
This function is for freeing any assigned memory to a matrix
for its columns and rows
*/
void Matrix::destruct ()
{
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < getHeight() ; i++ )
    {
        delete [] matrix[i];
    }
    delete [] matrix;
    matrix = NULL;
}
```

That is the first section, here is matrix multiplication

```
/**
This function overloads the times operator
*/
const Matrix Matrix::operator*(const Matrix &m)
{
    if(getWidth() == m.getHeight())
    {
        //i cant remember which way to do matrix mult, and im intoxicated
        //so heres a shitty implementation
        Matrix matrixResult(getHeight(), m.getWidth());
        int result = 0;
        int *row;
        int *column;

        cout << "\n\n matrix mult \n\n";

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < getHeight() ; i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 0 ; j < m.getWidth() ; j++ )
            {
                result = 0;
                row = getRow(i);
                column = m.getColumn(j);
                for( int k = 0; k < m.getHeight() ; k++ )
                {
                    result = result + (row[k] * column[k]);
                }
                matrixResult.setElement(i, j, result);
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < getHeight() ; i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 0 ; j < m.getWidth() ; j++ )
            {
                cout << std::setw(10) << matrixResult.getElement(i,j);
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }

        return matrixResult;
    }
    cout << "Not correct size to be multiplied";
    return *this;
}
```

And here is the equals (which is where i believed my error lies):

```
/**
Overloading the equals operator to be of
type Matrix. This function changes all
values of the currently instantiated matrix
to those of the one passed in via parameter
*/
Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix &m)
{
    //destroy previous matrix value array
    destruct();

    //Create a new array the same size as the matrix to be copied
    constructor(m.getHeight(), m.getWidth());

    //looping through the current array
    cout << "\n\n beginning equals\n\n";
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < getHeight() ; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < getWidth() ; j++ )
        {
            //changing current array's elements to
            //those of the paramter array
            cout << std::setw(10) << m.getElement(i,j);
            setElement(i, j, m.getElement(i, j));
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Just so everyone knows, i am COMPLETELY new to C++, and unfortunately our lecturer seems adamant on not giving us any practical session on C++ coding which is excellent :/

Furthermore, this is a partner programming exercise, so apologies if the code is not 100% conforming to standards, but some of it isn't my own!

Thank you!

EDIT: Implementation of getColumn as requested.

```
/**
This function returns the items in a specified column
within the matrix. The values are returns as a 1 dimensional
array, which has been malloc'ed.
*/
int* Matrix::getColumn(int col) const
{
    //using malloc to assign the memoru for the returned array
    int* result = new int[height];

    //check to ensure column was within matrix range
    if (col < width )
    {
        for( int i = 0 ; i < height ; i++ )
        {
            result[i] = getElement(i, col);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Edit 2: Command line output. PLEASE NOTE I AM COMPILING AND RUNNING THIS USING GCC THROUGH CODE::BLOCKS ON WINDOWS

```
       913       918      -418
       676       736       -25
      -225       265      -382


       890      -739      -452        87
      -331      -564      -761       280
      -375      -895       101       709


       829      -661       742       442
       679       567       377      -322
      -356      -136      -614      -356




 matrix mult




    665462   -818349  -1153492     40109
    367399   -892293   -868173    247167
   -144715    358705   -138547   -216213


 beginning equals

    197792    20092813134236931095717471
    200928    199968    2003201701603654
   -144715    358705   -138547   -216213

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.009 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: First, implement a copy-constructor and then we'll see. Also, I'd like to see the implementation of `getColumn`.

Comment: James, just FYI your `getColumn()` returns a dynamic allocation that is leaked in your multiplier function. This is, in a word, not good. Are you allowed to use `std::vector<>` for this problem? it will make your life a **ton** easier.

Answer (score -2):

change as this void Matrix::operator=(const Matrix &m){ ....}  and  delete the "return *this"

Comment: -1: No, don't do this. OP was correct with what `operator=` should return.

Comment: Hi there, i tried that just now and unfortunately get the same result. I will post my command line output to the main post now

Comment: Assignment operator in C++ should always return a reference to self.

Comment: It's back to the original now. I just dont understand why the first 2 rows just dont work. It's getting beyond me now. I've spent hours and hours trying to debug it :/